# cel_pgsql Inserting duplicate columns

Tags: asterisk, pbx, freepbx

The log shows there is duplicated columns, insert will fail.

```
[Aug 29 08:14:42] DEBUG[8683] cel_pgsql.c: Inserting a CEL record: [INSERT INTO cel ("id","eventtype","eventtime","userdeftype","cid_name","cid_num","cid_ani","cid_rdnis","cid_dnid","exten","context","channame","appname","appdata","amaflags","accountcode","peeraccount","uniqueid","linkedid","userfield","peer","id","eventtype","eventtime","userdeftype","cid_name","cid_num","cid_ani","cid_rdnis","cid_dnid","exten","context","channame","appname","appdata","amaflags","accountcode","peeraccount","uniqueid","linkedid","userfield","peer") VALUES (DEFAULT,'CHAN_END','2017-08-29 08:14:42.167195','','9004','9004','9004','','9001','9001','public','SIP/9004-00000008','','',3,'','','1503994474.12','1503994474.12','','',DEFAULT,'CHAN_END','2017-08-29 08:14:42.167195','','9004','9004','9004','','9001','9001','public','SIP/9004-00000008','','',3,'','','1503994474.12','1503994474.12','','')].


alp-test*CLI> core show version
Asterisk 14.4.1 built by buildozer @ build-3-6-x86_64 on a x86_64 running Linux on 2017-05-22 06:13:12 UTC
```

There is no update for cel_pgsql from 2015

**cel_pgsql.conf**

```
[global]
hostname=127.0.0.1
port=5432
dbname=ast
password=ast
user=ast
table=cel
```

**cel.conf**

```
[general]
enable=yes
apps=dial,park
events=APP_START,CHAN_START,CHAN_END,ANSWER,HANGUP,BRIDGE_ENTER,BRIDGE_EXIT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I load `cel_pgsql.so` two times, after remove `preload => cel_pgsql.so` everything is fine.